# Qt: two actions in menu (with the same text)

Tags: qt, menu

I create a menu dynamically. I add several checkable actions into one menu. Sometimes actions may have the same text that user sees. It's up to user (actually user adds commands into menu).

The problem is in this case clicking works wrong. If I click on the first action (from 2 with the same texts) everything is good but if I click on the second one, both actions are selected. I don't understand why. The code where actions have been created is here:

```
for (int i = 0; i< currentList.size(); i++)
{
  QString lanKey = currentList.at(i)->Language->toString();  
  QAction* lanAction = new QAction(this);
  QString name ="action_" + currentList.at(i)->Id->toString();
  lanAction->setObjectName(name);
  lanAction->setText(lanKey);
  lanAction->setCheckable(true);
  lanAction->setData(i);
  connect(lanAction, SIGNAL(triggered(bool)), this, SLOT(ShowSomething(bool)));
  ui->menuMy->addAction(lanAction);
}
```

Here, `lanKey` is language that may be the same for different actions. Anyway click on the specific action should lead only to checking of this action. What's wrong?

The slot is here:

```
void VMainWindow::ShowSomething(bool IsTriggered)
{
    QAction* senderAction = (QAction*)sender();
    int listIndex = senderAction->data().toInt();

    if (IsTriggered)
    {

        CreateEditor(subtitles, listIndex);
    }
    else
    {
        //hide this editor
        QString name = "editor" + editorsList->Id->toString();
        QDockWidget* editorDock = this->findChild<QDockWidget*>(name);
        if (editorDock != 0)
        {
            this->removeDockWidget(editorDock);
            this->setLayout(layout());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

The source of problem is found: it turned out that the slot finds the checked action wrong - by text, not by id.

Comment: This code looks ok.. Can you show the code of the `ShowSomething(bool)` method? The problem might be hidden in there

Comment: I've analyzed what the SLOT is doing and found the mistake! It turned out it finds the clicked action wrong, by text, not by name. Thank you Tim!

Comment: Looks like my answer was late haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find a logical issue in the code you posted so far. Here are a couple of options which I would try in order to resolve this problem:

1. Limit the users possibilities when adding items to a menu so that he can't add two items with the same name.
2. Add qDebug() output to `ShowSomething` to see if there is a problem with signals&slots. For example, if the slot gets called once for the first item but twice for the second item there is a problem there.
3. Debug into CreateEditor step-by-step.

As the problem seems to appear only for actions with a similar name, you should make sure that you never make a lookup of an action (or something related) by its `text()` but rather by its `data()` or `objectName()` (assuming that `currentList.at(i)->Id` will always be unique)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your answer, it's great and was very helpful, really.